# How is the word size often same as pointer size?

Tags: memory, computer-architecture

A pointer stores a memory address , so its size is the size of a memory address which depends on no of memory locations . On the other hand , Word size is the largest unit ,that an instruction can work/ works, on , So the size of a memory location is irrelevant, as multiple ones can be collected at a time. So what is the relation between word size and pointer size ?

Comment: "Word size is the largest unit" - This is false.  A pointer can be 32-bit or 64-bit all depends on the address size.  An instruction can accept, depending on the instruction, different byte size hence the reason there are 32-bit and 64-bit instructions. *this comment has been simplified for ease of writting it*

Comment: Please check 2nd answer http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48425/is-word-size-the-size-of-a-memory-location-the-size-of-the-data-bus-or-the-cp

Comment: @radhika Who told you that "Word size is the largest unit "? How about Long or longlong? If you take a look on  this [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)#Table_of_word_sizes) you would be surprised that word size is most unreliable data in term of size. It depended on CPU architecture that it runs

Comment: "But that same computer may be able to operate on bytes, 16 bit words, and 32 bit longwords." - this statement is correct the other is NOT 100% and has an engineer the details matter.  The entire answer you linked to isn't all that accurate, if I could issue a downvote, I would because I see numerous statements that are just flat out inaccurate.  ARM and x86 are basically the computer architecture world, and both depending on the specific processor, support variable word sizes.

Answer (score 2):

They don't have to be the same, and the number of computer systems where they aren't vastly outnumbers the ones where they are.  Still, there are some relationships between pointer size and "word" size.

Programs do a LOT of pointer arithmetic.  Array subscripting is pointer addition.  Pointers get compared to each other.  If your CPU can't do arithmetic on something the size of a pointer, your address has to be split across multiple variables, which results in a segmented or banked address space.  These are complicated to manage and cause proliferation of pointer-like types (near pointer, far pointer, based pointer).  As a consequence you get additional weird limitations such as linked lists being able to hold more items than an array can.

Still, microcontrollers with 8-bit data busses and larger address spaces (perhaps only for code and not data) are common.  In the other direction modern general purpose CPUs with 32-bit or 64-bit pointers have much wider data words than pointers (for example, 512-bit data words in the AVX subsystem of modern x86_64 CPUs).  Many lock-free algorithms depend on atomic access to data which are a minimum of twice the size of a pointer.

Comment: Word size is the maximum no of bits which the processor can execute simultaneously ,so this implies that ALU size and word size are same and ,hence,word size is architecture defined ,please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Also , If I talk about size of Memory data register and size of Data Bus , will they be same or different ?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Coincidence, probably.

A pointer isn't part of computer architecture per se, it is a programming language feature. For example the Windows API defines its own types of pointers and how large they are. In C on Windows, a pointer to a char (`char*`) varies between 32 and 64 bits depending on your version. The size of a word may have little to do with it.

[Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture)) is a very overloaded word, ahem, term. In CPU architecture a word can refer to the size of an instruction, the data bus, the memory bus, etc. In the [Windows API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx) a word is an unsigned short, i.e. *at least* 2 bytes, and thus depends on how shorts are implemented.

There may be a correlation between MS words and instruction size words, but I think you'd need an OS developer to debate that, and I doubt it will affect the size of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

At one time, computer registers and internal buses have gone from 4-bit, to 8-bit, then 16-bit, 32-bit and currently 64-bit. The maximum address space depends on the size of a pointer (though some early CPU's, e.g. Z80A, might *page* memory in chunks the size of a pointer).

As buses became wider, it was also desirable to increase RAM, so the size of a pointer also increased. Sometimes the OS did not keep up with the larger bus, though, e.g. [in the transition from Windows 7 32-bit to 64-bit, maximum addressable RAM at first moved from 4 GB to 8 GB, and finally 192 GB on high-end versions.](http://www.zdnet.com/article/max-memory-limits-for-64-bit-windows-7/)

So the size of the registers and of the bus (from a nibble to a byte, then a Word, then a DWORD in MS 16-bit OS, usw.) increased arbitrarily, as did the address space. [A more complete explanation is available from @DarkDust.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750140/whats-the-difference-between-a-word-and-byte)

Comment: 32-bit versions of Windows could have addressed more than 4GB per process but at the time there wasn't any commercial hardware nor software that justified the engineering cost to do so.  Linux having virtual zero development cost was able to use its near unlimited human man hours of development to do so.  What does the size of a memory registry within the CPU architecture have to do with physical system memory anyways?

Comment: It doesn't: it was simply arbitrary decisions to increase pointer size to allow addressing more RAM.

Comment: The need for larger variable types came as, you correctly indicate, the processors involved that capability.  Without the instructions to do so, they wouldn't exist, since there would be no way to manipulate them (add,subtract).  Again the pointer size has little do with RAM, virtual memory and page files solved many problems, but addressing 2GB vs 128GB had nothing to do with the instructions being introduced.  Your answer has potential though

Comment: The question was about the size of a *pointer*, which is used to address memory space and why it also increased as register width increased. Again, it was an arbitrary decision to allow larger programs and data sets without paging.

Comment: So what in general is the significant difference between word size , data bus width ,size of pointer and width of memory location ?

Comment: Word is defined by the programming language in other words it can be any size.  Data Bus is determined by the CPU architecture.  Size of the pointer depends on the address register being used.  Width of memory being used isn't a thing, or your using the wrong terminology.

Comment: A *pointer* is the determining factor that controls the size of address space, and is usually fixed for any OS. (Internal) bus width and register size are fixed by the CPU, and control how big a "chunk" of data is processed in a CPU cycle. Variable size is arbitrary, and within a program, some variable may be a single byte (Booleans, though theoretically one bit, actually consume a full byte for ease of addressing. How profligate!), a DWORD, or multibyte (as in floating-point numbers).

Comment: @Ramhound , I was actually talking about width of memory location ,BTW,I understood all the above points stated  ,but I am a bit confused with the actual terminology of saying a n bit micro controller ,It is said that n bits denote the size of ALU used in the processor , so is it that data bus width is also n bits , can it be less than or greater than n bits .Also Word size is the maximum no of bits which the processor can execute simultaneously ,so this implies that ALU size and word size are same and ,hence,word size is architecture defined ,please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Recall you have to decode the instruction, that outcome determines, what ALU operation is performed.  I have never heard of "width of memory location".  The results of an instruction goes into one of the processors registers.  Depending on the instruction a specific register size will be used, so again, "width of memory location" makes no sense or is odd terminology

Comment: Case in point the x86 processor has 128-bit, 256-bit, and 512-bit registers.  These can support QuadWord operations.  All this is documented by Intel.

Comment: Width of Memory location implies size of memory location .

Comment: As you said that outcome of  ALU is put onto one of the processor registers ,this implies that size of data bus and size of internal registers must be same Is it correct ?

Comment: @Ramhound , After reading more discussions regarding word size and data bus size , I am a bit confused regarding universal definition of a word .Please explain it briefly.I have gone through wikipedia ,it says " A word is a fixed-sized piece of data handled as a unit by the instruction set or the hardware of the processor" ,So does this imply that Memory Data Register size and Word Size are same ,i.e. 32 bit Micro controller = 32 bit word ,Is this terminology fine ?

Comment: @radhika: That's one candidate, but it isn't followed universally.  For example, the Windows typedef `WORD` is 16-bit, with `DWORD` meaning "double word" and `QWORD` meaning quad word... and Microsoft didn't invent this naming, some of the instructions in x86 and other architectures have `B`, `W`, `D` or `Q` signifying the operation width of 8-, 16-, 32-, or 64 bits.

Comment: If I talk about size of  Memory data register and size of Data Bus , will they be same or different ?

Comment: @radhika Why are you talking about those.  There are a finite number of registers, their "size", are determined by which register they actually are.